# Sequelize: Unhandled rejection TypeError: admin.hasOperation_sav is not a function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

**operation_sav** model is defined as follows:

> operation_sav.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var operation_sav = sequelize.define(
    "operation_sav",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
      },
      nom_operation: DataTypes.STRING,
      status: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM(
          "en_cours_livraison",
          "en_reparation",
          "repare",
          "expedie"
        ),
        defaultValue: "en_cours_livraison"
      },
      num_serie: DataTypes.STRING,
      address_mac: DataTypes.STRING,
      sous_garantie: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      description: DataTypes.STRING,
      adminId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      produitId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      status: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM(
          "produit_recu",
          "en_livraison",
          "en_reparation",
          "repare",
          "en_expedition",
          "expedie",
          "annule"
        ),
        defaultValue: "produit_recu"
      }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  return operation_sav;
};
```

*Notice there's an external foreign key* **adminId**
The relationship between table **Admin** and table **Operation_sav** is defined as follows:

```
  /** admin Has Many operation_sav*/
  model.operation_sav.belongsTo(model.admin, {
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
    onDelete: "cascade"
  });

  model.admin.hasMany(model.operation_sav, {
    foreignKeyConstraint: true,
    onDelete: "cascade"
  });
```

This is the function that creates a row inside the **Operation_sav** table:

```
var createSavOperation = function(operationInformation) {
  return models.operation_sav.create(operationInformation);
};
```

I have used it to create this row:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "nom_operation": "Répartion viwone plus",
    "status": "produit_recu",
    "num_serie": "5525ggffdd",
    "address_mac": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
    "sous_garantie": true,
    "description": "Panne bouton droit",
    "adminId": 10,
    "produitId": 6,
    "updatedAt": "2020-02-27T09:22:47.430Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-02-27T09:22:47.430Z"
}
```

Notice that adminId is **10** and operation_savId is **4**.  So I try to see if the whole association has worked properly by running this code:

```
  models.operation_sav.findByPk(4).then(operation_sav => {
    admin = models.admin.findByPk(10);
    admin.hasOperation_sav(operation_sav);
  });
```

However, I get this error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: admin.hasOperation_sav is not a
>   function

Is this because I have manually written the **adminId** value when creating that **operation_sav** row?

**EDIT 1:** When I added this console.log line:

```
  admin = models.admin.findByPk(10);
    console.log(admin instanceof models.admin); // false!!
    admin.hasoperation_sav(operation_sav);
```

I get **false** which doesn't make any sense but it kindof explains why sequelize is not throwing the *admin.hasoperation_sav is not a function* error..
**EDIT 2:** I have fixed **EDIT 1** like this:

```
 models.admin.findByPk(10).then(adminFound => {
      console.log(
        "admin is instance of models.admin",
        adminFound instanceof models.admin
      ); // true
      adminFound.hasoperation_sav(operation_sav);
    });
```

But, **hasoperation_sav** is still unrecognized as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this:

```
  models.operation_sav.findByPk(4).then(operation_sav => {
    models.admin.findByPk(10).then(adminFound => {
      console.log(
        "admin is instance of models.admin",
        adminFound instanceof models.admin
      );
      // admin is instance of models.admin true
      adminFound.hasOperation_sav(operation_sav).then(result => {
        console.log("admin has operation sav", result);
        //admin has operation sav true
      });
    });
  });
```